# Why is considering only quadratic in one of the variables of a two variable quadratic sufficient for calculating roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots, quadratics

Find the $positive$ integral solutions to $7x^2-2xy+3y^2-27=0$

My solution:

Assuming the quadratic in $x$ , if we assume one root to be integral , the other has to be rational (as y must be an integer to satisfy the condition so ,product of roots is rational)

For the roots to be rational the $discriminant$ has to be a perfect square. We get the discriminant($\Delta$) as

$\Delta=4(189-20y^2)$ which has to be a perfect square.

So we get $y^2$=$1,9$ hence $y$ as $1,3$

putting the values back we get the pair $(x,y)=(2,1)$

If we again make a quadratic in $y$ we get the same solution. Hence considering a quadratic in $x$ only is sufficient.

My Question:

I don't get the fact or intuition behind as to why does considering the quadratic in either $x$ or $y$ is self sufficient as it is not symmetric. If someone could provide me the intuition or proof behind as to why both of them lead to the same results , it would be of great help.

Note: All the similar questions I have encountered can be solved by considering only quadratic in either $x$ or $y$ only, so i assume it is general.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for solutions among $(x,y)$ where $x$ is restricted to be integer. But clearly, the integer solutions in $y$ all belong to this subset and you won't miss any.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are nonzero, we can solve the equation$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+d=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$for $x$ by considering the equation as a quadratic in $x$, namely$$x=\frac{-by \pm \sqrt{(by)^2-4a(cy^2+d)}}{2a}, \tag{2}\label{2}$$and for $y$ by considering the equation as a quadratic in $y$, namely$$y=\frac{-bx \pm \sqrt{(bx)^2-4c(ax^2+d)}}{2c}.\tag{3}\label{3}$$

Please note that \ref{1}, \ref{2}, and \ref{3} are the **same** equations, so solving each of them alone is sufficient to find all roots.

So, for example, if you want to find all positive integer roots of the equation$$7x^2-2xy+3y^2-27=0,$$both \ref{2} and \ref{3} will give you the same results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if i had been allowed i would have accepted yours also as

Answer (score 0):

Assume that someone told us that $y=1$, then the question would be to find the integer solution to:
$$7x^2-2x+3-27=0.$$

In other words the intuition comes from the fact that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a root of $F(x,y)=0$, then $x_0$ is a root of $F(x, y_0)=0$. Which is easy to prove by contradiction.

Comment: I still could not get why considering only one of them is sufficient and if we dont know the integral value that satisfies the equation, if you would please elaborate